# How to reset the drop-out mask for custom RNN cells after every calls of ```keras.layers.RNN```?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am new to TensorFlow and I am trying to make a custom RNN cell that behaves like a stacked LSTM cell, with residual connection between LSTM layers. Each LSTM layer also has drop-out implemented. So far I've tried to subclass `keras.layers.AbstractRNNCell`, but during training, the drop-out mask of the cell is not reset after every batches when I iterate the cell with `keras.layers.RNN`. I've read the source code of `keras.layers.RNN` and I found out that it only resets the drop-out mask for cells that are instance of `DropoutRNNCellMixin` via method `_maybe_reset_cell_dropout_mask`.

My question is: How do I reset the drop-out mask of my custom cell after every calls of `keras.layers.RNN`?

The following is the code that I wrote and its behavior. I'm using Tensorflow version 2.5.0:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class StackedLSTMCell(layers.AbstractRNNCell):
    def __init__(self, params, **kwargs):
        super(StackedLSTMCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.params = params
        self.depth = params['depth']
        self.units = [layers.LSTMCell(params['hidden_dim'],
                             dropout=params['dropout_rate_input'],
                             recurrent_dropout=params['dropout_rate_output'],
                             unit_forget_bias=True,
                                     name=f'LSTM_{i}')
                             for i in range(params['depth'])]
    @property
    def state_size(self):
        return tuple(self.units[i].state_size for i in range(self.depth))

    @property
    def output_size(self):
        return self.units[-1].output_size

    def get_config(self):
        return {'params': self.params}

    def get_initial_state(self, inputs=None, batch_size=None, dtype=None):
        return tuple(self.units[i].get_initial_state(inputs, batch_size, dtype) \
                     for i in range(self.depth))

    def call(self, token, inp_state):

        input_sum = token
        out_state = []
        for i in range(self.depth):
            h, h_and_c = self.units[i](token, inp_state[i])    
            if i+1<self.depth:
                token = layers.Add()([input_sum, h])
                input_sum = layers.Add()([input_sum, token])
            out_state.append(h_and_c)
        return h, tuple(out_state)

params = {
    'hidden_dim':128,
    'dropout_rate_input':0.2,
    'dropout_rate_output':0.2,
    'depth':3}

cell = StackedLSTMCell(params)

RNN = layers.RNN(cell, return_sequences=True)

inputs = tf.ones((1, 1, 128)) #input shape format is (batch_size, time_steps, features)

print(set([RNN(inputs, training=True).numpy()[0, 0, 0] for _ in range(5)])) 
#return: {-0.19621503}
#RNN returns same output every calls.
```

Here is the desired behavior, taking the example of `layers.LSTM`:

```
RNN = layers.LSTM(
    params['hidden_dim'],
    dropout=params['dropout_rate_input'],
    recurrent_dropout=params['dropout_rate_output'],
    return_sequences=True)

print(set([RNN(inputs, training=True).numpy()[0, 0, 0] for _ in range(5)]))
#return: {-0.053168092, -0.016183555, -0.024903715, -0.040428974, 0.025961103}
#RNN returns different outputs after each call.
```

This is the source code of `keras.layers.RNN`:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L198-L1002

Thank you for spending time for my problem. Any idea is appreciated.